# How can I split the string into float numbers in c#?

Tags: split

I have the each strings. I want to split these into float numbers in c#.
I tried this code

```
string[] values = text.Split(new char[] { ' ', '\t' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

but it is not working properly. Sometimes there are 5, 6 or 7 elements in the values.

```
0.007   -0.008   -1.008   -0.951    0.687    0.000    0.826    0.622   -0.899

0.004   -0.003   -0.998    0.409    0.969    0.000    0.826    0.656   -0.899

0.014   -0.026   -1.006    0.491   -1.731    0.000    0.924    0.600   -0.898
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
string[] values= text.Split(null);
```

or

```
string[] values= text.Split(new char[0]);
```

to split by white space and parse each string to float

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting by `null`

```
 var text = "0.007 -0.008 -1.008 -0.951 0.687 0.000 0.826 0.622 -0.899";

 var values = text.Split(null).Where(s => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s)).ToList();
```

If `null` then white-space is assumed to be the splitting character.

Comment: The "text" variable has only 1 line.

Comment: I can't use the Where method.

Comment: What output do you get without the `Where` method?

Comment: Error 10 There is no definition on 'Where' in 'System.Array'

Comment: I mean if you just enter use `var values = text.Split(null);`